# Remove Excel AddIn from the list of available addins

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-dna

Is there a way to remove an addin from the list of available addins in Excel?
I run into a problem because i have two addins required for my 'workflow'. I have a COM addin with some functions and a ribbon in Excel. Besides that i have an addin in the xll format based on the ExcelDna package for my user-defined functions (because ExcelDna provides intellisense for UDF). My worksheets require the UDF's from the xll-addin. I have written a subroutine that checks if the latest version of the xll-addin is installed, if not it replaces it for the newest version. The code i have written works when i test it. But when i close and reopen Excel it runs into an exception on this line `dnaAddin = addIns.Add(GetDnaAddinDestinationPath)`. It seems like Excel renames the xll-addin when closing (see attached image).[The selected addin is the renamed one. The activated one is the addin's real name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJRLR.png)
I want to remove the renamed addin from the list because that seems to be a problem.

Check the subroutine below:

```
    Public Shared Sub ActivateDnaAddin()
        Dim sourcePath As String = GetDnaAddinSourcePath()
        Dim destPath As String = GetDnaAddinDestinationPath()
        Dim filePath As String = ""
        Dim dnaAddin As AddIn = Nothing

        If IsExcel64Bit() Then
            Dim addIns As AddIns = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AddIns
            For Each addIn As AddIn In addIns
                If addIn.Name = DNA_ADDIN_FRIENDLYNAME Then
                    'this is where i want to remove the addin.
                    addIn.Installed = False
                End If
                If addIn.Name = GetDnaAddinFileName() Then
                    filePath = addIn.FullName
                    dnaAddin = addIn
                End If
            Next
        Else
            Dim addIns As AddIns2 = CType(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AddIns, AddIns2)
            For Each addIn As AddIn In addIns
                If addIn.Name = DNA_ADDIN_FRIENDLYNAME Then
                    addIn.Installed = False
                End If
                If addIn.Name = GetDnaAddinFileName() Then
                    filePath = addIn.FullName
                    dnaAddin = addIn
                End If
            Next
        End If

        If dnaAddin Is Nothing Then
            GoTo InstallAddin
        Else
            GoTo RefreshAddin
        End If

InstallAddin:
        File.Copy(sourcePath, destPath, True)
        If IsExcel64Bit() Then
            Dim addIns As AddIns = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AddIns
            dnaAddin = addIns.Add(GetDnaAddinDestinationPath)
        Else
            Dim addIns As AddIns2 = CType(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AddIns, AddIns2)
            dnaAddin = addIns.Add(GetDnaAddinDestinationPath)
        End If
        dnaAddin.Installed = True
        Exit Sub

RefreshAddin:
        Dim dateInstalled As DateTime = GetFileCreationDate(filePath)
        Dim dateBase As DateTime = GetFileCreationDate(sourcePath)
        If dateBase.Equals(dateInstalled) Then
            If Not dnaAddin.Installed Then
                dnaAddin.Installed = True
            End If
        Else
            If dnaAddin.Installed Then
                dnaAddin.Installed = False
            End If
            GoTo InstallAddin
        End If
        Exit Sub

    End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.